# How can I resize my Jupyter notebook screen to its previous size?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

The size of all characters, boxes and the format of my Jupyter notebook doubled in size all of the sudden, and it is difficult to visualize my code and the obtained results. All other programs have "normal" visualization, so, it`s not a computer resolution problem, it only occurs with the Jupyter notebook...
How may I go back to the "normal" view of my Jupyter notebook?
I am using Jupyter Version 5.7.4.

I read all the Jupyter documentation and I was not able to find a solution...

```
All characters doubled in size
```

I would like to go back to normal size view of the Jupyter notebook...

Comment: Did you try Ctrl+- (Control + minus)?

Comment: That was the right thing to do @Ken White! Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem, as indicated by @Ken White, is to use Ctrl+- (Control + minus) to reshape the Jupiter notebook appearance and size it properly.